# Official PS3 Controller Keyboard as input device to PC

Tags: controllers, ps3, windows-7, keyboard

Is it possible to use my official PS3 Controller Keyboard (you know, the one that attaches on top of the PS3 Controller) to my Windows 7 PC?

It would be nice to have functionality like touch sensitive mouse and keyboard via Bluetooth.

Comment: What sort of connector does it have?

Comment: It's a bluetooth device. It has a USB connector, but that doesn't send controller data through it AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

It would need a custom driver. Here is the one for the SIXAXIS game pad, however there are issues with unsigned drivers like having to select the 'use unsigned drivers' option from boot up.
http://news.filefront.com/how-to-use-a-ps3-controller-on-a-pc/

Sony seems to have issues with using their hardware on other systems so you wont ever find a legit driver.

Comment: Thanks ... I've seen drivers for SIXAXIS and DUAL SHOCK 3 controllers... but I was wondering if there were any drivers for the keyboard as well.